# FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, firebase

After migrating to Firebase Cloud Messaging.When opening my app it crashes and throws an error saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.` I already put my new google-services.json and update my SDK.

Here's my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Check Google play service
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

}
}
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Please do double check, you added

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of app's gradle file and then clean and rebuild the project

Comment: I removed the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`  from my app gradle but encounter a new error when calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` in my `MainActivity` my app crashes.

Comment: my bad... i needed to add the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' ` ?  trying to add it i still encounter error. it says `Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"`

Comment: Hi Mori, you can ignore this error as of now and they will fix this issue in the next release. thats what firebase team says :) .

Comment: When I add this I get: "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeModernDebugResources'.
> [string/google_api_key] /<path>/app/src/main/res/values/defaults.xml [string/google_api_key] /<path>/app/build/generated/res/google-services/modern/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources"

I also did not see this step in the setup or migration guides for FCM. Do you have a link I may have missed?

Comment: Flutter may require `flutter clean & flutter run` as suggested in the answer as well.

Comment: What if I use Firebase Java Admin? (Java Backend and not Android client app)

Answer (score 21):

Not sure, if it is relevant here. But there is another scenario when this crash can happen.

---

If your app has a service (with different process) and you're creating your own `Application` class, the service and the foreground app will use the same Application class (**not same instance**) to initialize. Now when I am using `com.google.firebase:firebase-crash` dependancy to handle crashes, it creates a background service `your.app.packagename:background_crash`. For some reason, this was inducing crashes on my app. Specifically, because in my Application class, I was making a call like,

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

I am assuming, the background service when initing with our Application class, somehow Firebase is not initialized. To fix this, I did

```
if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty())
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This also happens with ads. If a user clicks on an ad then returns to the app Firebase with no longer be available.

Comment: @Codevalley, In my case, there was another process (Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor) called app:editor. It was using same application class, thus trying to get token from non-existing firebase app. Checking before getting token solved my problem. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 12):

I've had similar problem, and for me it was a bug/problem with manifest merger. I've found out that `FirebaseInitProvider` has not been injected into final manifest file because of `tools:node="replace"` in my app's manifest file. So, try to remove this xml tag and `FirebaseInitProvider` will be injected and Firebase can be initialized properly.

Comment: can you please update your answer for those who are not much familier with merger tool @jmodrako

Comment: Currently i have updated to tools:replace="android:name" instead of tools:node="replace". hope that help

Answer (score 11):

**build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

**\app\build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ..
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ..
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Error:(90, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Answer (score 10):

@jmodrako answer solved my problem... `tools:node="replace"` to `tools:node="merge"`

Explained... on AndroidManifest.xml

**From**

```
<application
...
tools:node="replace">
```

**To**

```
<application
...
tools:node="merge">
```

**Merge problems with library themes?**
Build problems solved using `tools:replace="android:theme"`

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060272/2765087

Answer (score 2):

Move your firebase initialization inside the onCreate of Application class.
Also if you have enabled offline persistence,  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true) should come before any other initializations.

Comment: clicked down vote accidentally now so not allowing me to upvote :(

Answer (score 2):

Verify all configurations as below:

1-firebase project setting: 
google-services.json is correct?
[image]

2- add firebase SDK
[image]

3- clean - rebuild your project

hopefully, this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin
```

And the following line to project build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio

1. apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  (build.gradle - Module layer)
2. Menu~>Build~>CleanProject

Works for me ok.

Answer (score 0):

In your dependency just add:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
...
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}
```

apply `plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score 0):

Register your application in Firebase and copy the google-services.json to your root project.

Apply  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0` to you root build.gradle.

Apply `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services` to your project gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Build Action (GoogleServicesJson) to the File Name Google-Services.Json.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not initializing Firebase on app startup, I had to do the following to resolve it

```
@Service
public class FirebaseSetup implements CommandLineRunner {
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        initializeFirebase();
    }
    private void initializeFirebase() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:ssf1-v1-firebase-adminsdk-zr72u-afcb5bc13b.json"));
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)).build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add   `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` to `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        ..
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

Add this at the end of the app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This worked for me