# Initialization of FirebaseApp in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I tried to create a login form in android studio and integrated the new firebase https://console.firebase.google.com and change my code from legacy to new one.

I'm getting this after executing my application,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT]
>   doesn't exist.

I don't know how to set or to initialize this with the new Firebase. This is what I did for Authenticating the user and getInstance.

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseApp app = Firebase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_NAME);
```

in this part i have an error does anyone has Idea?

Comment: Hello guys thank you for viewing this question and I got a new reply from firebase I for got to add the classpath : classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' and the plugin for google play services :// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' hope will help you guys

Comment: make sure to add the package to your firebase project and make sure to download the google json from firebase and embed to your android project, next check the package name to your android project name, for me this solved the error the default_name_user from firebaseApp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseApp with name \[DEFAULT\] doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist)