# How can i make the app work offline with Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app gets the data while its connected to internet but I want the app to get the data offline from cache. Please help I'm new to Firebase.

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: @Abhishek The link you have shared is for Cloud Firestore and not for Firebase real-time database as the OP asked.

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply activate `offline persistens` as specified in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities):

> Firebase applications work even if your app temporarily loses its network connection. You can enable disk persistence with just one line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this it will help for you

First create an application class

```
public class BaseApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    Picasso build = builder.build();
    build.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
    build.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(build);
}
}
```

Keeping the data fresh using the below line

```
DatabaseReference mRootRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images");
mRootRef.keepSynced(true);
```

More details on persistence and syncing can be read here in the Firebase documentation:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities