# Unable to resolve symbol storageRef in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using fire base to store the images in that i am getting a error in storage Ref unable to resolve the symbol please help.

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
public static final String GridViewDemo_ImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pencilrulerlearner/";
StorageReference riversRef;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    File targetDirector = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file1 : files) {
        Uri file= Uri.fromFile(file1);


        storageRef.child("images/" + file.getLastPathSegment());
      UploadTask  uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);


        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        });
    }

}
}
```

Even i changed the storageRef to riversRef where i am getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at nidhinkumar.firebaseexample.Sample.onCreate(Sample.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
```

Comment: Where did you initialize `storageRef`?

Comment: are you 100% sure that file!=null
If file is null than you try add that path: images/<null>

Comment: storageRef is not initialized

Answer (score 4):

You're getting this error because `storageRef` variable hasn't been initialized. Any attempt to invoke a method on a `null` reference will lead to `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

In your case you should first get a reference to the `FirebaseStorage` instance:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
```

Then, you can get a reference to the storage you want, by `getReferenceFromUrl` method.

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("Url to storage");
```

Hereinafter `storageRef` is initilized and can be used.

Comment: i have initialized the storagereference but i am getting the following error:                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: how i have to do it can u tell me

Comment: @AbacusRathu Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/3924/firebase-storage/13664/firebase-storage-operations#t=20160730103142745917

Comment: @AbacusRathu: Look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

The variable `storageRef` is not initialized.

First, create a `FirebaseStorage` variable:

```
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
```

Then initialize the `StorageReference` type variable `storageRef` like this:

```
storageRef = storage.getReference();
```

Answer (score 0):

StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

Answer (score -1):

do jus a simple thing import this file

`import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference`;

Your Welcome :)