# Firebase + RoboElectric: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase, robolectric

I am using **Firebase** in our android application for remote config. Below is the **initialization** done in my application class **onCreate** method:

```
    FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings settings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();
    remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(settings);
    setFirebaseDefault();

    Map<String, Object> defaults = new HashMap<>();
    defaults.put(FirebaseConstantsKt.BREAKING_NEWS, "");
    defaults.put(FirebaseConstantsKt.ENABLE_BREAKING_NEWS, false);
    FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaults);
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist) answer my `build.gradle` file also has the following line in it:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I run the application it works fine but when I try to run my Roboelectric test case it crashes with following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
>               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>               at com.woi.apppackage.android.MyApplication.initFirebase(MyApplication.java:225)
>               at com.woi.apppackage.android.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:107)
>               at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:140)
>               at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:433)
>               at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
>               at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
>               at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>               at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>               at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>               at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>               at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>               at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>               at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

The test has nothing to do with Firebase. If I comment out the Firebase code in `onCreate` the test runs fine. I think I am missing something in my initialization of Firebase

Answer (score 2):

This may be caused by Firebase Crash.  The current implementation of it creates a process called `background_crash`.  An instance of your `Application` class is created for each process of your app, including `background_crash`.  This is described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues).

Try adding this code to only initialize Remote Config when in your main process:

```
    if (FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        // In the crash process
    } else {
        // Not in crash process
        // Init Remote Config here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug with Firebase that is being called in Application level. I have the same issue with Firebase Database and got it resolved by moving my Firebase codes in my activity class, (SplashScreen in my case).

I suggest try doing the same. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
if (FirebaseApp.getApps(context).isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
}
```

just before you initialize firebase. This can happen if Firebase wasn't properly initialized (maybe because of an internal exception)