# Download file from Firebase Storage from background service

Tags: android, service, firebase, background-process, firebase-storage

I want to download an image file uploaded on Firebase Storage from background service of my application. I need service because the database is too large and storage also. That is why, I want to download all the data from Firebase in background to keep my UI consistent. All the data from Firebase Database downloaded successfully.But downloading file from Firebase storage gives me error.

**CODE :**

```
StorageReference httpsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);

httpsReference.getBytes(1024 * 1024).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        Log.v("log_tag", "onDataChange onSuccess icon received");
    }

}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

    }
});
```

**ERROR :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source)                      at in.co.cybercom.memorymatch.misc.WebServiceCommon.downloadImageSet(WebServiceCommon.java:133)
atin.co.cybercom.memorymatch.misc.WebServiceCommon.access$400(WebServiceCommon.java:49)
atin.co.cybercom.memorymatch.misc.WebServiceCommon$1.onDataChange(WebServiceCommon.java:91)
at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:158)
atcom.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                           atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Please let me know is it possible to download Firebase storage file in background service? If yes then how? and if not then is there any alternative for this scenario?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist ?

Comment: In your app manifest, have you declared your service to be in a separate process?

Answer (score 2):

"That is why, I want to download all the data from Firebase in background to keep my UI consistent."

Firebase Storage already performs downloads on a background thread precisely for this reason--you can kick off a download on the main thread and we'll fetch in the background, then raise the callback on the main thread. There's no reason for you to have to create a separate service to do this.

The Realtime Database does this as well. The whole point of Firebase is to prevent you from having to do any of this work :)