# java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

app base build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
/*compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'*/
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project level build

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

here is my logcat.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
```

After migrating to Firebase Cloud Messaging.When opening my app it crashes and throws an error saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist`. I already put my new `google-services.json` and update my SDK. I can't figure out the problem. I have implemented the same as what is on the Firebase documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @ Rushi M Thakker thanks budy your comment which refer to duplicate question solve my problem

Comment: No Problem Brother. My pleasure :)